# Add counter to nestjs cron job

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, nestjs

I'm using @nestjs/schedule and cron jobs in nestjs.
I need execute cron jobs limited ways, For example three times.
How can I do that?
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

## ┌────────────── second (optional)

## │ ┌──────────── minute

## │ │ ┌────────── hour

## │ │ │ ┌──────── day of month

## │ │ │ │ ┌────── month

## │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── day of week

## │ │ │ │ │ │

## │ │ │ │ │ │

## * * * * * *

Suppose you want your corn job run at 10:45 you simply replace the steric sign from hours and minutes position as shown above indications.

```
cron.schedule('45 10 * * *', () => {
  console.log('Running a job');
},
{
  scheduled: true,
  timezone: "Asia/Karachi"
});
```

Or suppose you want to run every day at specific hours

```
cron.schedule('0 10,11,12 * * *', () => {
  console.log('Running a job');
},
{
  scheduled: true,
  timezone: "Asia/Karachi"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your job dynamically and use the annotation timeout to finish it.

The timeout annotation needs time to finish your task, so, you need to calculate the time set to execute your job and multiply for the quantity of execution you want.

Here is an example of executing every 2 seconds and only three times. So, the final time to finish the job will be 2 * 3 * 1000 (or 6 seconds).

Pay attention that I had to add 1 second in timeout annotation, or the interruption would be executed on the third process and will execute only twice.

After that, you can delete the job or stop it. In my example, I decide to delete it.

```
private static time = 2;
private static quantity = 3;
private static limit = TaskService.time * TaskService.quantity;
private nameTask = '### TESTE  3 Times ###';

addCronJon(name: string, seconds: string, limit?: number) {
    const job = new CronJob(`*/${seconds} * * * * *`, () => {
      this.logger.warn(`time (${seconds} for job ${name} to run!`);
    });

    this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(name, job);
    job.start();

    this.logger.warn(
      `job ${name} added for each minute at ${seconds} seconds!`,
    );
  }



  threeTimes() {
    this.addCronJon(
      this.nameTask,
      TaskService.time.toString(),
      TaskService.quantity,
    );
  }

  @Timeout(TaskService.limit * 1000 + 1000)
  threeTimesTimeout() {
    this.schedulerRegistry.deleteCronJob(this.nameTask);
    this.logger.warn(`job ${this.nameTask} deleted!`);
  }
```

The complete code you can see [here](https://github.com/fabiana2611/nestjs2/blob/master/tasks/src/task/task.service.ts) .

The nestjs page about cron job you can access [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling)